# couldn't start mysql in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I start mysql in xampp I am getting following errors.

```
08:46:20  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
08:46:20  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
08:46:20  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
08:46:20  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
08:46:20  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
08:46:20  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
08:46:20  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Mysql log

```
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1870647
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1870656; transaction id 460
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191120  8:46:19
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-20  8:46:19 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Please help me to resolve this as I am new to this stuff.

Comment: Are these logs complete, check if you could find [Error] instead of the [Note] in logs.

Comment: yes these are complete logs and I couldn't find any error logs under mysql logs

Comment: can you give us the output for netstat -ano | find "3306" . May be there's an other service or duplicate sql using the port

Comment: I checked netstat -ano | find "3306". There are no active connections to that port.